# $\arctan (x) + \arctan(1/x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, geometry, trigonometry, intuition

> How can I show that $\arctan (x) + \arctan(1/x) =\frac{\pi}{2}$?

I tried to let $x = \tan(u)$. Then

$$ \arctan(\tan(u)) + \arctan(\tan(\frac{\pi}{2} - x)) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

but it does not seem useful.

> I'd appreciate most a proof that gives intuition and / or uses geometric
>   insight.

Answer (score 7):

Inasmuch as the OP requested an approach that is intuitive or geometric, let's proceed accordingly.  The ensuing heuristic discussion serves only to supplement the more analytical/rigorous approaches, and can help solidify the understanding of the relationship.

Suppose we have a right triangle formed from the three coordinate points $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,x)$.  Note that the tangent of angle $\theta$ between the hypotenuse and the $x$ axis is

$$\tan \theta =x \tag 1$$

We also can see that the tangent of the opposite side angle $\phi$ is

$$\tan \phi = 1/x\tag 2$$

But we know that the sum of the angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ must add to $\pi/2$.  We have, therefore, from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that

$$\theta +\phi =\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)=\pi/2$$

While in this development, the angles were restricted to be between $0$ and $\pi/2$, we can adapt this same approach show that the relationship is indeed general for $x>0$.  And we can also use this approach to show that for $x<0$, $\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)=-\pi/2$.

Comment: Thanks for a simplistic answer, and yet rigorous as usual.

Comment: @Shailesh Wow.  Thank you for the nice comment!  And you're very welcome.

Comment: without sacrificing your privacy, somehow I feel that you were my professor in early 80s

Comment: @Shailesh Well, I am not that old.  Just curious, but what makes you think so?   I am happy to have a private conversation off line.

Comment: sure. The topics you address, the clarity and fluency and the initials.

Comment: @Shailesh I am from the US.  Still in contention?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27193/discussion-between-shailesh-and-dr-mv).

Comment: @Shailesh I joined the chat room, but didn't see you there.

Answer (score 4):

$$f\left( x \right) =\arctan { \left( x \right) +\arctan { \left( \frac { 1 }{ x }  \right)  }  } $$
$$f^{ \prime  }\left( x \right) =\frac { 1 }{ 1+{ x }^{ 2 } } -\frac { 1 }{ 1+{ x }^{ 2 } } =0$$
$$\\ f\left( x \right) =c\\ f=f\left( 1 \right) $$

Comment: What happens if $x<0$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $$\tan ^{-1}(x)=\theta\iff x=\tan \theta$$ Where, $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$

Now, we know $$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)=\cot\theta$$
$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)=\frac{1}{\tan\theta}$$
Setting $\tan\theta=x$
$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)=\frac{1}{x}$$
$$\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
$$\theta+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Setting value of $\theta$
$$\tan^{-1}\left(x\right)+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\arctan(x)+\arctan(\frac1x)$. Then $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{1+1/x^2}\frac{-1}{x^2}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{1+x^2}=0$ so $f(x)$ is constant for $x>0$. Then note that $f(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and thus $f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

There is a discontinuity at $x=0$, so the derivative only makes sense for $x\neq 0$. When $x<0$, you can check that $f(-1)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$. $f(x)$ has the same derivative so for $x<0$, $f(x) -\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @VincenzoOliva I meant 1, sorry.

Comment: What happens if $x < 0$?

Comment: If $x<0$ the equality is not true.. This is valied only for $x>0$. If $x<0$ then:

$$\arctan x + \arctan \frac{1}{x} = - \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: @avid19 you might want to edit the answer and distinguish the cases for $x>0, \;\; x<0$. (+1) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

$\arctan(a)+\arctan(b)
=\arctan(\frac{a+b}{1-ab})
$.

Therefore
$\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)
=\arctan(\frac{x+1/x}{1-1})
=\arctan(\frac{x+1/x}{0})
=\pi/2
$.

If this bothers you,

$\begin{array}\\
\arctan(x-c)+\arctan(1/x)
&=\arctan(\frac{x-c+1/x}{1-(x-c)/x)})\\
&=\arctan(\frac{x-c+1/x}{c/x})\\
&=\arctan(\frac{x^2-cx+1}{c})\\
&=\arctan(\frac{x^2+1}{c}-x)\\
&\to \pi/2
\quad\text{ as } c \to 0\\
\end{array}
$.

Answer (score 0):

Letting $x=\tan u$, we have
$$\begin{array}{lll}
\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)&=&\arctan(\tan u)+\arctan(1/\tan u)\\
&=&\arctan(\tan u)+\arctan(\cot u)\\
&=&\color{blue}{\arctan(\tan u)+\arctan(\tan (\frac{\pi}{2}-u))}\\
&=&u+\frac{\pi}{2}-u\\
&=&\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{array}$$
The line highlighted in blue should be similar to your equation (note the difference though).

Comment: Thanks but you seem to have shown the equality for all $x \in \mathbb R$. But it only holds for $x>0$. Where is the mistake in your proof? I don't see it.

Comment: $\arctan(\tan t)$ is not necessarily equal to $t$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So.. this answer is wrong?

Comment: The  use of it is fine in this case for positive $x$.

Comment: Nice catch Andre. Here is my error. Suppose that $u=-\theta$, $0\lt\theta\lt\frac{\pi}{2}$, then $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-u)=\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta)$. Observe that
$\arctan(\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta))=-\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta$, not $\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta$. Oopsy!